# how to run phpunit test in laravel controller?

Tags: php, laravel, unit-testing, laravel-5, phpunit

```
i want to run phpunit test in controller for


adding some data  in database and  testing api of project both
```

PostAddTest class

```
namespace Tests\Feature;

use Tests\TestCase;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\WithFaker;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\RefreshDatabase;
class PostAddTest extends TestCase
{
    /**
     * A basic test example.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function testExample()
    {
        $api = "/post/add";
        $request = [
            'title' => "xyz form....",
            'content' => 'post add by xyz user.'
        ];

        $response = $this->postJson($api,$request);

        info("daa : ".print_r($response->getContent(),true));
        $this->assertTrue(true);
    }
}
```

if i run using phpunit then successfully worked

`vendor/phpunit/bin --filter testExample`

```
PHPUnit 6.5.5 by Sebastian Bergmann and contributors.

.                                                                   1 / 1 (100%)

Time: 6.84 seconds, Memory: 28.00MB

OK (1 test, 1 assertion)
```

i  got success but

if i run  using controller then i geting error like this

> Call to a member function make() on null {"exception":"[object]
>   (Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError(code: 0):
>   Call to a member function make() on null at
>   PostProject/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Testing/Concerns/MakesHttpRequests.php:335

MainController

```
public function index() {
      (new PostAddTest)->testExample()  
}
```

Comment: What do you mean "run using controller"? Are you opening the @index method manually through the browser?

Comment: run particular phpunit test  run in controller @index method by browser

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should call the `setUp` method first. Like this:

```
$postAddTest = new PostAddTest;
$postAddTest->setUp();
$postAddTest->testExample();
```

---

---

I don't know your use case but if you really want to run your tests in the controller, as **alternative** you could use [Symfony Process](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/process.html) and do this:

```
use Symfony\Component\Process\Process;
...
public function index() {
  $process = new Process(array('vendor/bin/phpunit', '--configuration', 'phpunit.xml'), base_path());
  $process->run();

  // (Optional) Get the phpunit output
  $process->getOutput();

}
```

or use PHP **exec()** function http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php

Comment: i wan to run particular test using `Symfony Process`  how can i do that

Comment: Add -- filter testExample  to the array in new Process: array('vendor/bin/phpunit', '--configuration', 'phpunit.xml', '--filter' ,'testExample')

Comment: Also if you want to execute all the tests in a specifc directory (e.g tests in the directory tests/Unit) the change the array to: array('vendor/bin/phpunit', '--configuration', 'phpunit.xml', 'tests/Unit')

Comment: now sending request successfully but not a waiting for response get empty output only  ..